# handy methods to fetch multiple records in ruby and add to single variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

For `booleans` I can use this in ruby and it works.

```
@listing=listing.draft? && listing.published?
```

But what if I have multiple queries which returns an `array` or something

Lets say `drafts` and `published` are two `methods` on the `model` which returns `array` of `listings`

so any `handy method` to get both like `&&` and `||` in boolean?

If i do below code I can see that only the last query(`after &&`) gets saved always and the first one(`before &&`) gets overriden..

```
@listings=listing.drafts && listing.published
```

> PS: I know I can get each seperately and push that to an array but as
>   there are out of the box methods for booleans is it possible to do
>   that for non boolean queries?

Comment: You can use `listing.where(status: [:draft, :published])`. If you are using enum then replace names(draft and published) with enum values.

Comment: @jaspreet21anand  Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listing.where(status: [:draft, :published])`.
This will fire a `IN` query if using SQL database.
If you are using enum then replace names(draft and published) with enum values.